# Equipartition Theorem for the microcanonical ensemble - valid only in the thermodynamical limit?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature

I'm following the derivation of the equipartition theorem for the microcanonical ensemble, as I have seen it on wikipedia.
In the end, it derives:
$$
\langle x_m \frac{\partial H}{\partial x_n} \rangle = \delta_{nm} \frac{1}{\frac{\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial E}}{\Omega}}
$$
And then they use $S = \log \Omega$ to arrive at the temperature. What bugs me about this is that $\Omega$ is not the partition sum of the microcanonical ensemble here:

$$
\Omega = \int_{H<E} d\Gamma
$$
While
$$
Z_{\text{microcanonical}} =  \int_{H=E} d\Gamma \approx  \frac{1}{\Delta E} \int_{E < H < E + \Delta E}
$$

Here $\Gamma$ denotes a microstate (in statistical mechanics, that would be an element of phase space).
I have read that for large N, most of the volume lies in the surface of a hypersphere with dimension N, and because of that this approximation of $\Omega = Z$ can be made, but does that also mean that the equipartition theorem for the microcanonical ensemble is only valid for large N as well?

To me that's shocking, as the equipartition theorem is the way of obtaining microscopic temperatures from systems (for example when you simulate a system with 100 particles and then calculate a temperature for each timestep).
Can we somehow safe the derivation?

Edit: As I have read now in this[question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135302/strange-definition-of-microcanonical-partition-function/541452#541452), there is a different entropy used in this formula that is also called "Gibbs Entropy". This entropy strangely yields the correct temperature in the equipartition theorem.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\int H$ and $E d\Gamma$?

Comment: @GiorgioP I corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have met the same problem reading that. I did some research and found this paper helpful: https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2889939

The authors of this paper argue that for microcanonical ensemble, it is the Boltzmann-Planck definition $S=k\ln\omega$ that should be used, where $\omega$ is the number of microstates with total energy being held strictly fixed at $E$. The equally division of kinetic energy is still valid:

$$\langle\mathbf{p}_i\cdot\nabla_{\mathbf{p}_j}H\rangle = \delta_{ij}2\frac{\langle K\rangle}{N} = \delta_{ij}\frac{2}{N}\langle\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}\rangle$$

But because of the use of $\omega$ instead of $\Omega$, now $\langle K \rangle$ has no direct relation to the temperature. The temperature is related to the kinetic energy by:

$$\left(\frac{3N}{2}-1\right)kT=\left[\langle K^{-1}\rangle\right]^{-1}$$

This implies that if we want to calculate the temperature of a microcanonical ensemble, we should calculate the ensemble average of the **inverse** of the kinetic energy.

The result above can be derived as follows. We assume that the Hamiltonian can be expressed as

$$H = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\mathbf{p}_i^2}{2m_i} + U(\mathbf{r}_1\ldots,\mathbf{r}_N)$$

The number of microstates in a microcanonical ensemble is

$$\omega(N,V,E) = \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int\delta(E-H) d^{3N}rd^{3N}p$$

So the temperature can be calculated as

$$\frac{1}{kT} = \frac{\partial\ln\omega}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int\delta^\prime(E-H) d^{3N}r d^{3N}p$$

To evaluate that, we can perform the Laplace transform on it ($E$ to $s$):

\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{\partial\ln\omega}{\partial E}\right] &= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int\int\delta^\prime(E-H)e^{-sE}dE\ d^{3N}r d^{3N}p
\\&= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int se^{-sH}\ d^{3N}r d^{3N}p
\\&= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int s\exp[ -s (\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\mathbf{p}_i^2}{2m_i} + U)] d^{3N}rd^{3N}p 
\\&= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g}（2\pi)^{3N/2} \prod_{i=1}^Nm_i^{3/2} s^{-(3N/2-1)} \int e^{-sU}d^{3N}r
\end{aligned}

By inverse Laplace transform we can get

$$ \frac{1}{kT} = \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} （2\pi)^{3N/2} \prod_{i=1}^Nm_i^{3/2} \int \frac{(E-U)^{3N/2-2}}{\Gamma(3N/2-1)} \Theta(E-U) d^{3N}r$$

where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function. On the other hand, the ensemble average of the inverse of kinetic energy is

$$\langle K^{-1}\rangle = \langle (E-U)^{-1}\rangle = \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int \frac{\delta(E-H)}{E-U} d^{3N}pd^{3N}r$$

The Laplace transform of this is

\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left[\langle K^{-1}\rangle\right] &= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int \frac{e^{-sH}}{H-U}d^{3N}pd^{3N}r
\\&= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} \int \frac{ \exp(-s\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}) }{ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i} } d^{3N}p \int \exp(-sU) d^{3N}r
\end{aligned}

To calculate the integral over $p$, we can make a coordinate transform $p^\prime_i = p_i/\sqrt{2m_i}$, and let $\xi^2 = \sum {p^\prime}^2$:

\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left[\langle K^{-1}\rangle\right] &= \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} 2^{3N/2} \prod_{i=1}^Nm_i^{3/2} \int \frac{e^{-s\xi^2}}{\xi^2} d^{3N}p^\prime \int e^{-sU} d^{3N}r
\\&=\frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} 2^{3N/2} \prod_{i=1}^Nm_i^{3/2} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-s\xi^2}}{\xi^2} A(\xi)d\xi \int e^{-sU} d^{3N}r
\end{aligned}

where $A(\xi)$ is the surface of a 3N-dimension sphere with radius $\xi$ and is equal to

$$ A(\xi) = \frac{2\pi^{3N/2}}{\Gamma(3N/2)}\xi^{3N-1}$$

Substitution of this into the integration above yields

$$\mathcal{L}\left[\langle K^{-1}\rangle\right] = \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} (2\pi)^{3N/2} \prod_{i=1}^N m_i^{3/2} \frac{1}{3N/2-1} \int \frac{e^{sU}}{s^{3N/2-1}} d^{3N}r$$

By inverse Laplace transform, we can finally get

$$\langle K^{-1} \rangle = \frac{1}{\omega} \frac{\Delta E}{g} (2\pi)^{3N/2} \prod_{i=1}^N m_i^{3/2} \frac{1}{3N/2-1} \int \frac{(E-U)^{3N/2-2}}{\Gamma(3N/2-1)} \Theta(E-U) d^{3N}r$$

By comparing this with the result of $1/kT$, we can easily find

$$\left(\frac{3N}{2}-1\right)kT=\left[\langle K^{-1}\rangle\right]^{-1}$$

So using different definitions of entropy yields different results. The authors elaborated on why they believe $S=k\ln\omega$ is the right one to use. They calculated the distribution of speeds using both $\omega$ and $\Omega$ and demonstrated that only the former is consistent with their MD simulation of 10 hard-sphere particles. Since the entropy can also be seen as an ensemble average ($S=-k\langle \ln\rho\rangle$, $\rho$ is the probability density of a microstate), it is reasonable to do it in the phase space $\omega$ too. Also, they found that $\langle K\rangle_\Omega=\sum\langle p_i^2\rangle_\Omega / 2m_i \not= \langle E-U\rangle_\Omega$ and this result is considered as not physical. Those who approve the use of $S=k\ln\Omega$ often cite the result that $\Omega$ is adiabatically invariant, but this reason is insufficient in the authors' opinion.

The authors also derived the result for $NVE\mathbf{PG}$ ensemble in which total momentum $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{G}=t\mathbf{P} - M_{total}r_c$ are also constant. This is important for molecular dynamics simulation because most of the time we do the "$NVE$ ensemble MD", we only simulate once and then calculate the time average. If there is no external force, what we get is actually a $NVE\mathbf{PG}$ ensemble. The results are slightly different:

$$\langle\frac{\mathbf{p}_i^2}{2m_i}\rangle = \frac{M_{totle}-m_i}{M_{total}(N-1)}\langle E-U\rangle + \frac{Nm_i-M_{total}}{2(N-1)M_{total}^2}\mathbf{P}^2$$

$$\left(\frac{3(N-1)}{2}-1\right)kT=\left[\left\langle \left(E-U-\frac{\mathbf{P}^2}{2M_{total}}\right) ^ {-1} \right\rangle\right]^{-1}$$

In the thermodynamic limit where $N$ is large, the result of the equipartition theorem and the results derived in this paper for $NVE$ and $NVE\mathbf{PG}$ ensemble become equivalent. So in that case it's still safe to use the equipartition theorem to calculate the temperature in $NVE$ MD simulations.

Comment: Thank you for the paper. The including discussion is extremely enlightening. .